# Combining multiple audio files for real-time playback on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, audio, core-audio

I'm trying to build a feature into an iOS app of mine that will take four .WAV audio files, combine them and play them back in real time. Essentially I just want to set up some kind of callback loop that would feed data to the output audio buffer. I've done something similar with CoreVideo where I set up a compositor and then got a startVideoCompositionRequest call back that would feed me a frame, which I could manipulate and then output to the renderer... I was hoping for a similar way to manipulate audio streams.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
Output Sample = A*sampleA + B*sampleB + C*sampleC + D*sampleD
```

where A, B, C, and D are just scaling coefficients that can be updated in real time by user-facing controls. I've searched around for the solution and it seems that I should be able to achieve this with Core Audio, but I haven't found many examples that do a similar thing, and any that I have found are years old and riddled with deprecated calls.

I've looked in to the open-source iOS audio library Novocaine (https://github.com/alexbw/novocaine) which purports to abstract a lot of the low level CoreAudio set up code, but after playing around with it I haven't been able to achieve what I'm hoping for, and the documentation seems a little thin.

I'm a total beginner with audio on iOS so any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can pull samples out of all 4 .wav files using the AVAssetReader API, calculate your resulting sample values and put the resulting samples in a circular buffer.  Then have the RemoteIO Audio Unit callback pull them out of the circular buffer for play-out.  Alternately, you can use a kAudioUnitType_Mixer node audio unit in front of the output audio unit, and feed the mixer callbacks from your .wav asset samples.  Then let the mixer unit will do all the math with your scaling coefficients.

More info is in Apple's Core Audio documentation and guides.